# Replace entire line inline with sed but skip one starting with #

Tags: sed

I'm trying to do an inline replacement using `sed` in an EC2 Amazon instance running their standard Ubuntu flavor but I can't seem to figure out the right syntax.

Basically I need to edit the `java.security` file in a couple locations so I'm using `find` + `sed` to do it and it works perfectly as expected but then, when the tests are completed and I do the cleanup, I want to return it to the expected default values I want and that's where I'm running intro trouble.

This is how my stock file looks like:

```
:/etc/java-8-oracle/security# cat java.security | grep jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms
#   jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, SSLv3, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768
```

And I want to replace that second line with another value (not append).

If I do this:

```
find / -name java.security -type f -exec sed -i  's/jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=*/jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768/g' {} +
```

It will just append it so I'll end up with an increasingly longer and useless string every time it runs.

but if I do this:

```
find / -name java.security -type f -exec sed -i  '/jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=*/c\jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768' {} +
```

It replaces both the string I want and the commented example which leaves me with 2 identical and uncommented lines.

I'm using `find` because I need to edit 3 files in different locations at the same time. I'm narrowing it down to `/` now just for testing and trial/error purposes.

Anyone knows where I'm screwing up or what I'm missing?.

Thanks!.

Comment: Try to use a starting anchor like `^jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` in your sed (second find attempt0

Comment: I think that actually did the trick! Thanks :D. Think you could post it as an answer so I can select it? Also, if you wanna explain why the `^` the did trick I definitely wouldn't mind.

Comment: I was expecting to do the trick. `^` in regex captures the beginning of the line. Similarily `$` captures the end of the line. Those two symbols are called anchors in regex. So by using `^pattern` you force to capture lines that begin with `pattern` and not with `#pattern`. See here http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#anchors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already gotten a working solution in the comment: refine your regex to only match entries starting with `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`. I've still opted to post an answer since the question you've asked (or at least its title) was slightly different and I felt compelled to elaborate on that in case you were still curious and also someone else landed her searching for an answer how to skip a specific line. So here we go:

In sed commands like `s` can be preceded by an address or address range which they apply to, so while this:

```
$ sed -i 's@\(jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=\).*@\1NEWVALUES < 768@g' FILE
```

Would replace each occurrence of `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` with `NEWVALUES`.

```
$ sed  -i '/^#/!s@\(jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=\).*@\1NEWLIST < 768@g' FILE
```

Would not do that for any lines whose first character is `#`. `/^#/` matches such lines and `!` is a logical `not`. Only execute the command for lines not matching.

I've also used back reference (to make the line shorter and reduce risk of typos, also during maintenance). And I used `@` instead of `/` since I try to go for more visually distinctive separator especially if I have other (back)slashes around. If you wanted to be consistent with that across the board, you could replace the initial `/^#/` with `\@^#@`.

Generally though it is indeed advisable to write your regular expressions to match accurately exactly what you want to match.